# Java how to deserialize object of a class that contains a variable length string?

Tags: java, oop, deserialization, distributed-system

I am implementing a distributed flight booking system using Java and I have a class Flight.

Flight.java

```
public class Flight {
    private int flightId;
    private DateTime departureTime;
    private float airfare;
    private int seatAvailability;
    private String source;
    private String destination;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param flightId
     * @param departureTime
     * @param airfare
     * @param seatAvailability
     * @param source
     * @param destination
     */
    public Flight(int flightId, DateTime departureTime, float airfare, int seatAvailability, String source, String destination) {
        this.flightId = flightId;
        this.departureTime = departureTime;
        this.airfare = airfare;
        this.seatAvailability = seatAvailability;
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    //getters and setters
```

The source and destination fields are variable length strings. For this project, we are not allowed to use Java object serialization facilities and input/output stream classes in Java. How do I deserialize the source and destination fields?

Comment: Which format are you trying to Serialize/Deserialize it to/from? Also, where do you plan on storing the serialized output, if you cannot use an OutputStream? Your DateTime (JodaTime?) might also be variable length. What have you tried?

 I don't understand this question at all.

Comment: In my opinion using Java object serialization for a network protocol is a bad idea as it always serializes data and the code (-> possible security problem, unnecessary lare size of transmitted objects). Use a serialization to JSON e.,g. using Jackson or Guava to (de)serialize network data.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke The whole project is done in Java, so big endian format. The serialized output will be stored in a buffer array. The DateTime class is a custom class that takes in year, month, day, hour and minutes all as integers.

Comment: To serialize variable length data you can do what many binary serialisation formats do: they first write the length of the data and then the data itself.

Comment: @ThomasKläger *To serialize variable length data you can do what many binary serialisation formats do: they first write the length of the data and then the data itself.* That's going to be tricky if using `OutputStream` is not allowed ;)

Comment: @g00se if it's possible to write `int`s  into some kind of output buffer (be it a byte array or whatever) the it should also possible to write a length (in the form of an `int`) and a number of characters (also in the form of `int`s) into the same output buffer :)

Comment: @ThomasKläger But how is that buffer going to get from A to B without an `OutputStream`?

Comment: @g00se not my problem - the OP seems to know some way because apparently the OP has some way to serialize / deserialize the other fields. My comment is only about an idea how to extend that existing serialization / deserialization to accomodate for variable length strings, not for how the solve the complete problem.

Comment: @g00se for example, the OP could use a `ByteBuffer` to create the serialized data and then use in-memory-sharing between processes to give another process access to the bytes. Or the task could to create a `List<Integer>` that contains the serialized data and to take such a `List<Integer>` to reconstruct the object - transfering the data would then be handled by outside code.